# Set ngModel and ngModelChange programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

I can do the following in HTML:

```
<input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="..."
    (ngModelChange)="..."  />
```

Now I have to set ngModel and ngModelChange programmatically in a Typescript-Function. This is my function:

```
public AttachUserSelector(inputElement: HTMLInputElement, options: UserSelectorOptions) {
    // TODO: set ngModel and ngModelChange for inputElement
    //       ngModel should bind to the property options.model
    //       ngModelChange should bind to the function options.modelChange(event: any)
}
```

Can someone help me, how I can do this?

Comment: You are maniac! in the good sense of the word :)

Comment: You can easily proxy `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` through local properties and methods, e.g. `[ngModel]="localModel"`, `get localModel() { return this.options.model; }`. But odds are you're solving the problem you're having in a wrong way. You probably want to implement [CVA](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) instead.